# Reload a page using javascript inside a script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using this [script](https://github.com/nicholasruggeri/cookies-enabler.) to block 3th part google scripts ( european cookies law)

It works but with some google maps scripts, after clicking "ok" to accept, i need to reload the page to see the map

```
<script src="cookies-enabler.js"></script>
<script>
    COOKIES_ENABLER.init({
        scriptClass: 'ce-script',
        iframeClass: 'ce-iframe',
        acceptClass: 'ce-accept',
        dismissClass: 'ce-dismiss',
        bannerClass: 'ce-banner',
        bannerHTML: '<p>Questa pagina usa cookies di terze parti. Per maggiori informazioni:<a href="privacy.php"> Privacy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; Per continuare: '
                    +'<a href="#" class="ce-accept">'
                    +'Accetto i cookies'
                    +'</a>'
                    +'</p>',
        eventScroll: false,
        cookie: {
            name: 'ce-cookie',
            duration: 365
        },
        preventIframes: true
    });
</script>
```

How can i put some javascript code here to reload automatically the page on click?

```
   +'<a href="#" class="ce-accept">'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With pure JS, just use the `window.location.reload()` method:

```
+'<a href="javascript: window.location.reload()" class="ce-accept">'
```